# Qt-C++ connect Sqlite by absolute path

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

I have a Qt project with absolute path.

```
QString path_to_db = "F:/Binh_Efeis/resources/database/efeis.sqlite";
```

When I build this project and run it (as `F:/Binh_Efeis/debug/EfB.exe`), it works fine.

**But** we can't use absolute paths when deploying to other systems.

We wish to use a relative path.

Comment: Check your working directory. Relative paths are relative to the working directory (e.g. `../resources/database/efeis.sqlite`)

Answer (score 1):

Check your working directory - or 'current' directory (naming preferred by Windows API).

Relative paths are relative to the working directory (e.g. `../resources/database/efeis.sqlite`, if the 'current' directory is `F:/Binh_Efeis/debug`)

**EDIT** Set the working directory from within the IDE using:

[image]

See [Creator Run Settings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-run-settings.html) for more information

Comment: It's my structure : F:\Binh_Efeis\ - debug
                                   - headers \ helper \ common_helper.h(This file contain relative path).So that,I will make a relative path:     QString path_to_db = "../../resources/database/efeis.sqlite";  .Is it right?

Comment: No. The location of a source file is irrelevant. You should make it relative to the _working directory_ of your application. This is a property of the runtime environment, and has ***nothing*** to do with your source code.

Comment: If I use QT-Creator IDE,When press Ctrl+R - it's mean run - It show           [pre]  Dir:  "F:/Source/release/EfB.exe" 
       F:\Source\release\EfB.exe exited with code 0 [code]----..If I use qmake and run "mingw32-make debug-all" ,It will generate .exe to debug folder.If we use it,It's connect to database .sqlite fine.

Comment: It's work fine if we use COMMAND LINE.It's either work or not work when we use QTCreator IDE.

Comment: @BinhTieu Set the working directory for debugging in the project properties. I don't have QtCreator so I can't do the screen shot

Comment: @BinhTieu but luckily QtCreator has online docs. There you go, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) is better than using the current directory. I have used 3rd party libraries that change the current dir, which will cause problems if other parts of the program rely on the value of the current dir.

Comment: Dear Roku,With QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() ,It will show build folder . In my case,It will show F:/build-EfB-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug folder.May you give me any solution?

Comment: @Roku You can't make the OS interpret interpret paths relative to anything other than the current working directory. You make a good point, but that's hardly the problem of the OP: he doesn't grok relative paths. Anyways, I'll +1 if you show the portable Qt code to build a path relative from the `applicationDirPath()` because it might help the OP

Comment: @sehe If you are using _only_ the relative path, then, of course, the path can only be relative to the current dir. But just prepend the relative path with the absolute application dir path, and there you have a path relative to the application path: `QString path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/database/efeis.sqlite";`